# Pdf no valido en Acrobat Reader con itext

Tags: java, itext, firma-digital

Me encuentro implementado la firma digital con itextpdf. Ya tengo firmado el documento con un certificado .p12 pero, al momento de abrir el PDF y validar con Adode Reader, me sale el mensaje que el certificado es inválido. He verificado el mismo documento con el programa valida4ng y se encuentra válido.

¿Alguna observación respecto a esto? ¿Cómo puedo solucionar el problema?

Comment: Por favor, añade el código con lo que lleves (o un [mcve] si es posible) y una descripción más detallada del error (¿algún código?¿cuál es el mensaje exacto?)

Comment: Tengo problemas al validar el certificado cuando abro el documento firmado. En adobe reader me sale el siguiente mensaje " the singers identity is invalid" este documento lo firme con itext haciendo referencia al siguiente codigo:

Comment: http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-12. Utilizo el método public void signPdf(String src, String dest, boolean certified, boolean graphic) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, DocumentException {